How to determine which side (left/right or above/below) the normal of a 2D line segment points to?
I am working with 2D line segments and I need to calculate the normal of a segment. Given a line segment defined by two points
(x
1
,y
1
​
) and
(

2
,

2
), I can compute the normal vector as perpendicular to the direction vector of the segment. However, I am unsure how to determine on which side (left/right or above/below) the normal vector lies relative to the segment.
Here is what I have so far:

I can compute the direction vector of the segment as (dx,dy)=(x
2
−x
1
​
,y
2
​
−y
1
​
).
I calculate the normal vector as (−dy,dx).

Is it correct that the normal vector, as I calculate it, always lies to the left/above the direction vector?
Could someone explain how to figure out if the normal lies to the left or right (or above or below) of the line segment?
Any clarification on this would be greatly appreciated!

In the end, it should not matter. If, for example, you want the normal line through the point $p$ then both $r=p+tn$ and $r=p-tn$ will describe the same line, where t is any real number and n is a normal vector.

I suggest you read some basic information about writing mathematics at this site, see, e.g. How can I format mathematics, There should be universal LaTeX/MathJax guide for sites supporting it, and MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference

Just sketch vectors $(dx,dy)$, $(-dy,dx)$ and $(dy,-dx)$: you'll see by yourself.

If $k$ is the unit vector along the positive z axis (pointing towards your eye as you look down on the $(x,y)$ plane) then $k\times (dx,dy,0)$ will be normal to the segment in the plane and rotated 90 degrees anti-clockwise from it. If you do the cross product the other way around it will be a 90 degree rotation clockwise.

@Paul Thanks for your effort, but the question only relates to 2D space.

Based on the comments, I’ve realized that the side on which the normal vector lies relative to the 2D segment can be determined by how I compute it—either as
(−, ) or (, −). It ultimately comes down to a matter of convention and consistency in choosing one of these methods. The comments have helped me internalize this, and I’ve decided to consistently compute the normal vector as
(−, ) in my software, ensuring that it always points to the left or above the segment. This will be the convention I follow in my implementation.
